# How to add a navigation item in Silverstripe while making a module?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to build a plugin/module for Silverstripe and I am trying to understand how to add a menu item in the CMS admin panel.

[image: CMS admin panel navigation]

This is where I want to add a new nav item and attach it to a view.

I looked through the API and I found [SilverStripeNavigatorItem.html](https://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/CMS/Controllers/SilverStripeNavigatorItem.html) this page but I am not sure how to use it.

I am using the [silverstripe-module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-module) module skeleton provided by Silverstripe official docs.

How do I add this navigation item in the admin panel and attach a view to it in the admin panel itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a completely custom admin screen we can create a class that extends `LeftAndMain`.

`app/src/Admin/TestAdmin.php`

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain;

class TestAdmin extends LeftAndMain
{
    private static $url_segment = 'test';
    private static $menu_title = 'Test';
    private static $menu_priority = 100;
    private static $menu_icon = 'public/images/treeicons/test.png';

}
```

`$menu_priority` allows us to set the order of the menu item relative to the other menu items. This is optional.

`$menu_icon` allows us to set a custom icon for our menu item. This is optional.

We then create a `TestAdmin_EditForm.ss` template with the following:

`app/templates/Includes/TestAdmin_EditForm.ss`

```
<div class="toolbar toolbar--north cms-content-header vertical-align-items">
    <div class="cms-content-header-info flexbox-area-grow vertical-align-items">
        <% include SilverStripe\\Admin\\BackLink_Button %>
        <% with $Controller %>
            <% include SilverStripe\\Admin\\CMSBreadcrumbs %>
        <% end_with %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel--padded panel--scrollable flexbox-area-grow cms-panel-padded">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer was really helpful, thank you, any idea on this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808724/how-to-add-javascript-to-all-pages-in-silverstripe-cms-via-a-module