# How to add javascript to all pages in silverstripe cms via a module?

Tags: javascript, php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to create a module for silverstripe. I am going through https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/requirements/#requirements to understand how to add javascript and css files to the front end pages.

What I am not able to figure out is how to add a javascript file to all cms pages when the user installs my module. Is there a class I can extend and specify there? Or can it be done using the config somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that subclasses `SilverStripe\Core\Extension`, and then apply it to `\PageController` using a [config YML file](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/extending/extensions/)

Your `Extension` class can then implement `onAfterInit()` to use the [`Requirements` API](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/requirements/)

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by adding the following to a .yml file:

```
SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_javascript:
    - your-namespace/your-module-name:javascript/file.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Both 3dgoo's and alt's answers are correct, depending on your use-case.

If you are wanting to add Javascript to all your front-facing "Pages" (What visitors see when navigating to your website **in most cases*), then you will want to follow [ant's example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62808724/9036577).

Otherwise if you are wanting to add the Javascript to your /admin section of your website,
so that CMS Administrators are impacted by your script, then you will want to follow [3dgoo's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825100/9036577).